# How to send back the data to react frontend after callback from google OAuth in django?

Tags: reactjs, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am working on an application with two parts as frontend and backend in react and django , I am using server side flow and using token authentication for login and authentication system with OAuth . When user clicks on the frontend on LOGIN WITH GOOGLE it is allowed to choose the email and login with the react server with port 3000 and the redirect url or callback url is my django backend with port 8080 and when it will be in production there will be an ip or domain for that . But now when i login with frontend , it goes to callback and sends all the data there . Now the thing is that after receiving the authorization_code  , getting access_token and then data , the request resides in the backend code and the connection with the react frontend is completely broken . Now I don't understand how to send data back to the frontend with auth token and all other data.

my views.py

```
"http://localhost:8080/api/callback/"
@api_view(["GET"])
def getCallBack(request , *args , **kwargs):
    if request.method == "GET" :
        data = {
            "scope" : request.GET.get("scope").strip().lstrip().rstrip() , 
            "authuser" : request.GET.get("authuser").strip().lstrip().rstrip() , 
            "prompt":  request.GET.get("prompt").strip().lstrip().rstrip() ,
            "code" : request.GET.get("code").strip().lstrip().rstrip() ,
            "client_id" :"",
            "client_secret" : "",
            "redirect_uri" :"http://localhost:8080/api/callback/",
            "grant_type" :"authorization_code"
        }
        response = requests.post("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" , data = data)
        token = response.json()["access_token"]
        payload = {
            "access_token" : token ,
        }
        response = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo', params=payload)
        data_dict = response.json()
        email = data_dict["email"].strip().lstrip().rstrip()
        try : 
            user = UserAccount.objects.get(email = email)
        except : 
            user = None
        if not user:
            return HttpResponse("You are not an authorized user or not a client , you cannot access the website !")
        try :
            token = Token.objects.get(user = user)
        except : 
            token = Token.objects.create(user = user  )
            token.save()
        
        return Response(
             {
                "token" : token.key,
                "some_extra_data" : "data" , 
            },
            status = status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

The thing is all the connection is broken with the react frontend and I want to make the user login with token auth in django so how to send this data back to frontend . Any help would be great .
Thanks .

Answer (score 3):

Let callback url be a frontend/React url and not backend.
Once google triggers this callback url, React will receive the request_params like access_tocken and send the access_token to you Django backend. Process your request and respond to React from where you can update the view to logged_in.

This will help achieve your requirement without losing connection to Django-backend.

Comment: Okay i get it . It is one of the way. But from https://www.hacksoft.io/blog/google-oauth2-with-django-react-part-2#server-side-flow-in-your-react-front-end  article I have setup the server side flow where the auth code , access_token is processed in the back end . Can i get the solution for this part where all the things are going on the back end ?? Is there any way to solve this issue .

Comment: The Blog already says you can redirect user to your react's url once you mark user as logged in

Comment: Yes , the thing works , but now the thing is that I am sending the redirect to the react page  : redirect("localhost:3000/api/logindata/" , data ) , how do i access the data in the frontend , the data is the dictionary which has auth token and few more details . How do i access that variable in react .

Comment: I know this is a rough answer but try using Cookies/Django_session to send the data and accessing it in React